# Groupby each group and then do division of two divisions (current yr/latest yr for each column)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, eval, division

I'd like to create a new column by dividing current year by its latest year in Col_1 and Col_2 respectively for each group. Then, divide the two divisions.

Methodology: Calculate (EachYrCol_1/Yr2000Col_1)/(EachYrCol_2/Yr2000Col_2) for each group

See example below:

| Year | Group | Col_1 | Col_2 | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1995 | A | 100 | 11 | (100/600)/(11/66) |
| 1996 | A | 200 | 22 | (200/600)/(22/66) |
| 1997 | A | 300 | 33 | (300/600)/(33/66) |
| 1998 | A | 400 | 44 | ............. |
| 1999 | A | 500 | 55 | ............. |
| 2000 | A | 600 | 66 | ............. |
| 1995 | B | 700 | 77 | (700/1200)/(77/399) |
| 1996 | B | 800 | 88 | (800/1200)/(88/399) |
| 1997 | B | 900 | 99 | (900/1200)/(99/399) |
| 1998 | B | 1000 | 199 | ............. |
| 1999 | B | 1100 | 299 | ............. |
| 2000 | B | 1200 | 399 | ............. |

Sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000],
                   'Group':['A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                         'Col_1':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
                         'Col_2':[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 199, 299, 399]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for helper DataFrame, so possible divide each column:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Group').transform('last')

df['New'] = df['Col_1'].div(df1['Col_1']).div(df['Col_2'].div(df1['Col_2']))
print (df)
    Year Group  Col_1  Col_2       New
0   1995     A    100     11  1.000000
1   1996     A    200     22  1.000000
2   1997     A    300     33  1.000000
3   1998     A    400     44  1.000000
4   1999     A    500     55  1.000000
5   2000     A    600     66  1.000000
6   1995     B    700     77  3.022727
7   1996     B    800     88  3.022727
8   1997     B    900     99  3.022727
9   1998     B   1000    199  1.670854
10  1999     B   1100    299  1.223244
11  2000     B   1200    399  1.000000
```